# Processing Order Status

Tags: orders, order-status

What does the "Processing" status mean (processing payment, shipment, ...) and where can I find a complete list of Magento statuses and their definitions?

Comment: processing status is set when payment is received and invoice is generated. Until then the order remains pending.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.mexbs.com/magento-order-statestatus-flow/

[image]

**Order "Pending"**
From the Admin panel, the sales order appears in the Order list as "Pending". At this point, payment has not been processed, and the order can still be canceled.

**Payment Received**
The status of the order remains "Pending" until payment is received. Depending on the payment method, you, may be notified when the transaction is authorized and in some cases, processed. The status of the order is now "Processing" and order can not be cancel and you will need to issue a credit using Credit Memos see http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/order-process-overview

Comment: Thanks for the scheme! And here is some additional scheme from the docs just for reference https://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/order-processing/order-workflow.html

Answer (score 1):

Angry Goomba,you can see list of status at  `admin>System>Order Statuses.`

```
an Order state have multiple Order status and One default status.
```

If you have set `a order state and it also changed the order status. it default Order status`

Processing means The `order status is Processing and it state also Processing`

Comment: Right but that's just a list, it doesn't define the different Statuses. How do I find out exactly what "Processing" means?

Comment: are you understand?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I understand that an order is labeled as Processing when its status and state are Processing but what I'd like is why its status would be Processing? Would that be due to a transaction problem, a shipping problem, something else?

Comment: yes.on order view page in admin is showing order status.

Comment: if my answer is statisfy my answer then accept answer

Comment: Generally when an order is placed it is sent to pending status while the customer is sent over to the payment gateway to make a payment. After completing the transaction successfully the order is put into processing status which basically signifies that it is in the process of being picked up from the warehouse and will be shipped and that everything is good with the payment.